# Why does my page get rendered all at once?

Tags: javascript, browser

My understanding is that the event loop can get a bit complicated. I'm fairly new to JavaScript and the web in general so it's even more complicated for me. However, I have a made a grid on the screen using grid layout. All I wanted to do was to fill each box with red color but I'd like to see this filling happen. What happens instead is that the loop is being computed and then everything gets rendered at the same time. How can I manage to make it look like an animation of some sort? Maybe point towards some resource so I can read about this? I searched for event loop, loops and renders but found way too much information. Any help thanks in advance!

```
for(let i = 1; i < 100; i += 2){
    setTimeout(() =>{
        const squareElement = document.querySelector('.grid :nth-child('+i+')');
        console.log('.grid:nth-child('+i+')');
        squareElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red';  
    }, 2000 );
}
```

There's my code. As you can see I even put a setTimeout so I can render one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't do what you expect it to do. You are expecting your code to run, wait 2-seconds, repeat 99 times.

```
for 1 to 100
 update one element to be red
 wait 2 seconds
```

Instead your code queues itself up to run 100 times, after waiting 2-seonds.

```
wait 2 seconds
for 1 to 100
 update one element to be red
```

A solution would to run your update element function, and at the end of execution, queue itself to run again after 2 seconds. Once it's modified all 100 elements, no longer set itself to run again.

```
function updateElement(i) {
   const squareElement = document.querySelector('.grid :nth-child('+i+')');
   console.log('.grid:nth-child('+i+')');
   squareElement.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; 
 

   // if there are more elements to update, run again after 2 seconds.
   if(i < 100) {
     setTimeout(()=>updateElement(++i),2000);
   }
}

// start the function after 2 seconds.
setTimeout(()=>updateElement(0),2000);
```

Comment: Yes I totally see what you mean, oh my god i feel so stupid. thank you!

Comment: No worries. Lemme tell you about all the errant semicolons in my life :)